# Custom event using @Input and @Output

Tags: angular, events

Trying to get my head around `@Input` and `@Output` and was hoping for an indications as to how my approach is wrong.

In the `app.component` PARENT COMPONENT I have the following

```
@Output() dateChanged = new EventEmitter();
dateSelected:any;

onDateSelected() {
   this.dateSelected = this.yearValue + "|" + this.monthValue;
   console.log(this.dateSelected);//is selected and prints out to console
   this.dateChanged.emit(this.dateSelected);
}
```

this is the html

```
<div>
 <!--app.component.html-->

      <app-expenses (dateChanged)="onDateSelected($event)"></app-expenses>
</div>
```

CHILD COMPONENT
In the child(ExpensesComponent ) component is as follow

```
 @Input() dateChanged: any;

 onDateSelected(e) {
   console.log(e);//doesnt reach this point
 }
```

onDateSelected doesn't fire of
What would be a good way of passing this date value to the child?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear from your code what is parent and what is child. To me it looks like `<app-expense>` might be child and `<app-component>` might be parent but then your question doesn't make sense. If the child emits the event why would you want `onDateSelected` be called on the child when the event is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Output()` events are for parents to listen for events of child components, not the other way around.

For parent to child communication you can use data binding.

```
<app-expenses [selectedDateInChild]="selectedDateOfParent"></app-expenses>
```

Comment: Cool thanks. is it possible to call a function in the child component from the parent that passes the date as a value?

Comment: You can make `selectedDateInChild` a setter then the code in the setter gets executed every time `selectedDateOfParent` changes